# Lot of System.Invalidoperation - SOS has no stack trace

Tags: c#, .net, azure-web-roles, sos

I have a Azure Web role. I have setup performance counters and one such counter is .NET CLR excpetions per sec. This seems to have a high value of 110 per sec. When i checked the process ump, I could see there are lot of System.InvalidOperationException . But in SOS when i type !pe fo rthat exception there is not stack trace and the exception message is "This exception should nver be thrown". Any pointers on where else i can look?

Comment: also use WPA for this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41467968/1466046