# Sos.dll and windbg Get exceptions thrown

Tags: c#, .net, windbg

I am using sos.dll and windbg to anayze a w3wp.exe dump. There is a high number of .Net CLR exceptions thrown per/sec shown in perfmon and i am trying to investigate this. I tried doing a !dumpheap -stat -type Exception. But does this show the exceptions that were thrown at the instance i took the dump or does this show all the exception object instances that were created? Exception object instances may be created without being thrown.

Is there a way to just get the exceptions that were thrown?

Comment: it shows all the exception created as they are already SO exception and OOM exception even they were not yet thrown

Comment: have you ever tried to use ETW to trace the exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the wrong tools. Install Windows Performance Toolkit which is part of the Windows 10 SDK. [The 1607 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) can be used for Win8/10 systems, [the older 1511 SDK](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=698771) can be used for Windows 7/2008R2.

Now use the [WPRP profile that I posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30289933/1466046) to capture the activity of your application by opening a cmd.exe as admin

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\wpr.exe" -start C:\DotNetRuntime.wprp
```

After captured some activity of your tool, run this command to stop the capturing:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\wpr.exe" -stop C:\Result.etl
```

Now make a double click on the `Result.etl` to open it in Windows Performance Analyzer and [load debug symbols](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/commercialize/test/wpt/load-symbols-or-configure-symbol-paths).

Now drag & drop the `Generic Event` graph to the analysis pane, order the colums for `Provider`, `process`, `Taskname`, `Field 1`, `Time`, `Opcode Name` and `Stack`. Now filter for the `Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntime` provider and expand your process name entry and next expand the entry for Taskname `Exception`:

[image]

Here in this demo, the VS Addon Resharper caused a `JetBrains.Application.Progress.ProcessCancelledException` . Check which excceptions you see for your process and check the stack where the exceptions are raised.

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions that are thrown are first chance exceptions. Since your program does not crash, this means they are caught and handled.

In addition to @magicandre1981's [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41467968/480982), I see two other options:

### ProcDump

[ProcDump](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx) can create crash dumps on first chance exceptions with the `-e 1` command line switch. Also define `-n` to specify the maximum number of dumps you want to take. Once you became aware of an exception and no longer want it to be reported, use `-f` to filter it.

Advantage: you do not only have the exception, you also have a call stack and all the heap information which you can analyze later.

Disadvantage: this will significantly slow down your process and take a lot of disk space.

### WinDbg exception commands

You could attach WinDbg to a process and use the `sxe` command with the `-c` switch to analyze first chance exceptions. Include `g` in the command to continue execution. It's helpful to write all output into a log file (use `.logopen`).

Example:

```
.symfix
.reload
.logopen c:\debug\logs\firstchance.log
.loadby sos clr
ld * 
sxe -c "!pe;!clrstack;g" clr
g
```

`.symfix` and `.reload` may not be necessary. Just make sure your [symbols are correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30019889/how-to-set-up-symbols-in-windbg), otherwise all the analysis may be useless. The `ld *` will just pre-load things to make the analysis faster later on.

Advantage: you can capture as many information as you want without creating huge crash dumps.

Disadvantage: The execution of commands may significantly slow down the process. WinDbg may become unstable when you do this with hundreds of exceptions. (I never did this for a long time, this warning is given based on my experience with WinDbg 6.12 somewhen in 2010)